# libGDX 3D Shadows

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, shadow

Im using libGDX and this is a Desktop project.

I have 2 models, one is the character and the other is the map, as you can see in the image below:

[image]

My question is:

How do I project the shadow of the character on the floor?

As you can see the character doesn't have a shadow, thus the Ambience Light. What do I have to use or how do I achieve this? Should I fake a shadow or is there a real way to project shadows?

Any comments or sugestions are welcome.

Comment: Render your model by supplying a `Environment` and add a `DirectionalShadowLight` to the environment first. However, this is an experimental class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
Environment environment;
DirectionalShadowLight shadowLight;

@Override
public void show() {
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch(); 
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 1.0f, 1f, .6f, 1f));
    environment.add((shadowLight = new DirectionalShadowLight(1024, 1024, 60f, 60f, .1f, 50f))                  
                .set(1f, 1f, 1f, 40.0f, -35f, -35f));   
    environment.shadowMap = shadowLight; 

    shadowBatch = new ModelBatch(new DepthShaderProvider());
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
        //create shadow texture
        shadowLight.begin(Vector3.Zero, camera.direction);
        shadowBatch.begin(shadowLight.getCamera());

        shadowBatch.render(instances);

        shadowBatch.end();
        shadowLight.end();

        //render scene
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


        modelBatch.begin(cam);      
        modelBatch.render(instances, environment);  //environment has shadowMap!
        modelBatch.end();
}
```

Comment: ShadowMap and DirectionalShadowLight is deprecated. Would love to see a fresh answer.

Comment: It is actually a nightly release subject to change. Wondering if there is a proper way to add basic shadows from a directional light.

Comment: I ended up faking the light, by rendering a shadow.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime in 2015, a better shadow system was added to the libGDX testbed, separately from the "experimental, do not use" stuff mentioned in @Nolesh's answer.

The code is [in the libGDX tests](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/67781bd177e89fa78fd2730c342e1aae97c9ca59/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/shadows), so you'd need to copy it to your own project. A short description of how it works was [posted on the libGDX forums](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=84315#p84315) by the author, realitix. Note that there doesn't seem to be a fully runnable example, but the JavaDoc for the `ShadowSystem` interface contains the following:

```
// Init system:
Array<ModelBatch> passBatches = new Array<ModelBatch>();
ModelBatch mainBatch;
ShadowSystem system = new XXXShadowSystem();
system.init();
for (int i = 0; i < system.getPassQuantity(); i++) {
    passBatches.add(new ModelBatch(system.getPassShaderProvider(i)));
}
mainBatch = new ModelBatch(system.getShaderProvider());

// Render scene with shadows:
system.begin(camera, instances);
system.update();
for (int i = 0; i < system.getPassQuantity(); i++) {
    system.begin(i);
    Camera camera;
    while ((camera = system.next()) != null) {
        passBatches.get(i).begin(camera);
        passBatches.get(i).render(instances, environment);
        passBatches.get(i).end();
    }
    camera = null;
    system.end(i);
}
system.end();

HdpiUtils.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

mainBatch.begin(cam);
mainBatch.render(instances, environment);
mainBatch.end();
```

It's not as good as having a proper API for shadowing, but better than having to implement the entire thing from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas for your answer, have you tested this method? For me it doesn't work :( Do you have any update on this?

Comment: I have used it, and it does work. But you may need to do some additional legwork to get it right, like adjusting parameters and so on. Here's what worked for my specific situation: `new RealisticShadowSystem(
            AABBNearFarAnalyzer(),
            FixedShadowMapAllocator(2048, 4),
            BoundingSphereDirectionalAnalyzer(),
            FrustumLightFilter())`. You also need to add the lights to your shadow system. But to be honest, I wouldn't use libGDX for any but the most trivial 3D work again. It's great for 2D, but the 3D APIs, features and documentation are all lacking.

Comment: Yes I know, when I started studying it seemed like a good tool, but now that I have to do something of my own it is way too fragmented in documentation and maintenance. Except Unity, do you know any other good framework to develop 3D games (especially in Android)?

Comment: Godot's 3D is getting better all the time, but I've used it only for 2D so far. Unreal also runs on Android but I have no experience with it at all.

Comment: I tried this, replacing `new XXXShadowSystem()` with the code in @Thomas's comment, but the shadows were rendered completely black. (They should have been lit by the ambient light. Its level was 0.4.) Also, they had jagged edges, which could be mitigated by increasing the shadow map resolution (the `2048`), and some were partly culled (with a part nearer to the camera being culled, and a further away part not). (That might depend on settings of those parameters too.) @Nolesh's (accepted) answer worked well for me.